# Add Headers to a POST

Tags: vb.net, post, soap

I am trying to pass header when i post XML Data in VB.Net.

It needs to look like this :

```
POST /test1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.test1.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://test1.org/PostApplication_V5"
```

I am using the following :

```
Req.Headers.Add("POST /", "test1.asmx HTTP/1.1")
            Req.Headers.Add("HOST", "www.test1.com")
            Req.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
            Req.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "length")
            Req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", """http://test1.org/PostApplication_V5""")
```

Its not working

Comment: Most of these already have property on the Req that you can change instead of doing it on the headers. I don't think you want to send "length" to Content-Length, it's supposed to be a positive integer number, not a string. You can always use tool like fiddler to see what is hapenning. You also haven't specified what isn't working.

Comment: The code i provided does not output what it needs to look like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<POST /test1.asmx HTTP/1.1>
<Host: www.test1.com>
<Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8>
<Content-Length: length>
<SOAPAction: "http://test1.org/PostApplication_V5">

</POST /test1.asmx HTTP/1.1>
</Host: www.test1.com>
</Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8>
</Content-Length: length>
</SOAPAction: "http://test1.org/PostApplication_V5">
```